# How ignore inserting duplicate record into SQLite table?

Tags: android, sqlite, triggers

I need create trigger for sqlite database to ignore adding record. I have tables fan(idfan,fan unique), category(idcategory,category unique) and fan_category(idfc,idfan,idcategory). 
I created trigger. But not working as I expected.
Please help me anyone to solve this problem.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_ins BEFORE INSERT ON fan_category 
BEGIN
   CASE 
      WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM fan_category where idfan=new.idfan and idcategory=new.idcategory) THEN ROLLBACK
ELSE COMMIT
end;
END;
```

Comment: Triggers don't work like that. You want `INSERT OR IGNORE INTO ...`. see https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html

Answer (score 0):

You could actually handle this without even using a trigger, and I might recommend using an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` here:

```
INSERT INTO fan_category (idfan, idcategory, col1, col2, ...)
SELECT 1, 2, 'col1', 'col2'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM fan_category
                  WHERE idfan = 1 AND idcategory = 2);
```